# Unable to inject Ng-SweetAlert-2 in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

It is about [this project](https://github.com/JetFault/ngSweetAlert2)

I have followed the install process given in the description but I'm getting error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 19degrees.ngSweetAlert2Provider <- 19degrees.ngSweetAlert2 <- prkctrl`
```

I have included `sweetalert.js` (original `sweetalert`), `sweetalert2` (extended version) and `ngsweetalert2` (coming from this project).

I still dont see what is the reason? Name can be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added the module `19degrees.ngSweetAlert2` to your main application like:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['19degrees.ngSweetAlert2', /* and other modules */]
```

Comment: not related to this question but i think you can help me for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526016/angular-material-components-in-ng-sweet-alert-2