# Angular Material Components in Ng-Sweet-Alert-2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, sweetalert

I try to put an HTML code including Angular material input component (which is included in my project) in ng-sweet-alert dialog:

```
 var strVar="";
  strVar += "<div> <md-input-container style=\"padding-left:0px;\" flex=\"\">   

<label>Titel<\/label> <input ng-model=\"WBQuery.Titel\"> 
  <\/md-input-container> <\/div>";

swal({   
    title: 'HTML example',   
    html: strVar });
}
```

But what is shown is just the standard input field of HTML. Is there any (hacking) way to use angular material components in that dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but you can try this. After you have invoked the `swal` function, try the following:

(Assuming you are doing it in a directive or a controller)

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector(".sweet-alert"));
$compile(element.contents())($scope);
```

If that doesn't work, try to put the above code in a `$timeout` service:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector(".sweet-alert"));
    $compile(element.contents())($scope);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It will be good if you can provide me a plunkr or fiddle for it so that I can test.

Comment: I have a problem with 19degrees.ngSweetAlert2, is not firing the call back function. It was working well and then stop working, any information, links or comments related will be appreciated

Comment: Not sure, what changed in the code. Please try to post another question